# Trying to add a tuple in front of a list in Haskell but receiving error?

Tags: haskell

```
 type Name = String
 type PhoneNumber = Int
 type Person  = (Name, PhoneNumber)
 type PhoneBook = [Person]
 add :: Person -> PhoneBook -> PhoneBook
 add (a,b) 
 add (a,b) ++ []
```

I'm trying to add an entry in front of the list but its giving me an error

```
    Parse error: module header, import declaration
    or top-level declaration expected.
   |
30 | add (a,b) : xs
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by how you were attempting this, but you can already add an element to the start of the list with the `:` operator - so I think just `add = (:)` will do what you want. (And therefore there's no need to define your own function, either.)

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to add a list and a tuple. But `++` is defined for adding lists to lists, not for adding tuples to lists. Haskell is *very* strict about types, so it won't let you do this.

You should make the tuple a list:

```
add [(a,b)] ++ []
```

Or, as was suggesteed by Robin Zigmond in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54690135/trying-to-add-a-tuple-in-front-of-a-list-in-haskell-but-receiving-error/54690174#comment96167801_54690135), use the `:` operator:

```
add (a,b) : []
```

You have another issue though - your function definition should contain an `=` operator:

```
add (a,b) [] = [(a,b)]
```

This is how a function is defined in Haskell. On the lefthand side, it tells Haskell wat the inputs are. On the righthand side, it tells Haskell what they should be transformed into.

You may want to refer to [Learn You A Haskell : Syntax in Functions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) for a nice introduction to defining functions in Haskell.

Comment: but now im getting a   Illegal operator ‘++’ in type ‘PhoneBook add (a, b) add [(a, b)]
                                   ++ []’
      Use TypeOperators to allow operators in types      error

Comment: I don't see an `=` in what you wrote.

Comment: @MojibarHoman In a Haskell source file, you can't simply "add something at the beginning of a list", you need to define a function (e.g. `add`) which takes two parameters (e.g. a `person` and a `phoneBook`) and returns a new phonebook build from the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your post you can run the following piece of code:

```
 type Name = String
 type PhoneNumber = Int
 type Person  = (Name, PhoneNumber)
 type PhoneBook = [Person]

 add :: Person -> PhoneBook -> PhoneBook
 add (name, phoneNumber) phoneBook = (name, phoneNumber) : phoneBook 

 main = print $ add ("xyz", 987) (add ("abcd", 123) [])
```

which yields:

```
[("xyz",987),("abcd",123)]
```

Comment: Note that `add person phoneBook = person : phoneBook` would also work, since there's no need to access the `name` and `phoneNumber` here. (Above someone also has suggested `add = (:)` as an eta-contraction of that.)